# What is Magento Functional Testing Framework (MTFT)

Tags: magento2, testing, unit-tests

With the new release of **Magento version 2.2.2** in release notes they have mentioned a new feature as Magento Functional Testing Framework (**MTFT**). What is this framework do exactly?

Is this a option/replacement of **phpunit test**? Or is this something else? Has any one tried this?

Answer (score 3):

MFTF it's new framework for functional tests.
The release notes for [2.2.2](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.2CE.html) contains information about it.
Also, Magento dev docs contains [whole section](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/magento-functional-testing-framework/introduction.html) about it.

In general, this new framework based on [Codeception](http://codeception.com/), still uses Selenium and declarative XML style and will replace existing [MTF](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/mtf/mtf_introduction.html).

The main purpose of these both frameworks - functional tests. So, all unit, integration and API-functional tests won't be affected.

Comment: Correct!!! MFTF is the new Functional Testing Framework that will eventually completely replace MTF. One day all Automated Testing will be executable and reportable via MFTF, but for now we only support Functional Testing.

Comment: So do we get an option to use beteween phpunit and phpunit?